# postgresql view always shows nullable types in schema

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a service that will inherit the response type from its upstream table or view definition. When i define the table below column1 is set as NOT NULL. The schema in my view for example_view column1 after querying and explicitly defining as NOT NULL is still a nullable field. Is there any way to inherit the NOT NULL definnition in the parent table?

```
CREATE TABLE example_table ( 
column1 numeric NOT NULL 
);

CREATE VIEW example_view
SELECT
  column1
FROM example_table
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: No. A view doesn't preserve column constraints

Comment: While column constraints are not carried forward into the view definition they are still enforced as view is totally dependent on the table. So the where clause in your view definition query is redundant as it is **always true**, a null value cannot exist in the table because of the not null constraint. Like wise any attempt to insert null into the view will fail because of the table constraint.

Comment: Are you asking why the \d example_view displays "Nullable"? I think I have the same question if so and how to resolve it.

Comment: Yes, that is what i was getting at. How do i remove the nullable constraint on a view. It sounds like creating a view hides the constraint information of the underlying table so the optimizer defaults to nullable. I didnt't find a way to remove it and just created new tables by selection rather than working with view or materialized view. If you find a way to remove it let me know.